# SQL String - manipulation and parsing

Tags: sql, string

I'm working with some odd strings and trying to parse them.

example:  `ALS KICKBACK:AK:Acts1:SCErrors1:FErrors0:Overlays0`

The end result expected is as shown here:

[image]

I've cobbled together some code, but I'm not sure it will work in all scenarios. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
CASE WHEN [Short Description] Like 'ALS KICKBACK:%:Acts%' THEN Left(SubString([Short Description], PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [Short Description]), 8000), 
    PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString([Short Description], PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [Short Description]), 8000) + 'X')-1)   
WHEN [Short Description] Like 'ALS:KICKBACK:%:Acts%' THEN Left(SubString([Short Description], PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [Short Description]), 8000), 
    PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString([Short Description], PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [Short Description]), 8000) + 'X')-1)    
    ELSE '0'END as Acts
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend anything beyond trivial string operations in SQL owing to the language's lack of expressiveness and the rigid pure-functional style it mandates, without even intermediate variables (resulting in repeated `CHARINDEX` calls). Is there a reason you can't do this processing in client code?

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using? It looks like MS SQL Server - if so then you can simplify your code by using a scalar UDF and/or the embedded .NET runtime (SQL CLR) to do this instead of in T-SQL.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This is pretty easy in Postgres.

Comment: Using MS SQL 2014 DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is using a CROSS APPLY and a Parse Function

**Option 1: With a Parse Function**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[Short Description] varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'ALS KICKBACK:AK:Acts1:SCErrors1:FErrors0:Overlays0')

Select A.ID
      ,[Short Description]
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select  Acts     = max(case when PatIndex('Acts[0-9]%'    ,RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'Acts'    ,'') end)
                     ,SCErrors = max(case when PatIndex('SCErrors[0-9]%',RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'SCErrors','') end)
                     ,FErrors  = max(case when PatIndex('FErrors[0-9]%' ,RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'FErrors' ,'') end)
                     ,Overlays = max(case when PatIndex('Overlays[0-9]%',RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'Overlays','') end)
               From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.[Short Description],':')
       ) B
```

**Option 2: Without a Function**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[Short Description] varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'ALS KICKBACK:AK:Acts1:SCErrors1:FErrors0:Overlays0')

Select A.ID
      ,[Short Description]
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select  Acts     = max(case when PatIndex('Acts[0-9]%'    ,RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'Acts'    ,'') end)
                     ,SCErrors = max(case when PatIndex('SCErrors[0-9]%',RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'SCErrors','') end)
                     ,FErrors  = max(case when PatIndex('FErrors[0-9]%' ,RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'FErrors' ,'') end)
                     ,Overlays = max(case when PatIndex('Overlays[0-9]%',RetVal)>0 then replace(RetVal,'Overlays','') end)
               From  (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select [Short Description] as [*] For XML Path('')),':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                     ) P
       ) B
```

**Both Options Return**

[image]

---

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: @ChrisW Happy it helped

Comment: Beautiful John Cappelletti. Thank you so much. I didn't think of using a function for part of it. Extremely helpful.